# Max function to return null in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, max, min

For below input

```
Employee_ID Date_Column
100         12/12/2016
100         15/12/2016
200         19/12/2016
```

i used query

```
select employee_id,Max(Date_Column),Min(Date_Column) from Employee_ID where Date_Column is not null Group by Employee_ID
```

to retrieve Max and Min dates

But if my date_column has only one date for an employee both Max and Min function are returning same dates.

But my expected output is

```
employee_id Max(Date_Column) Min(Date_Column)
100         15/12/2016       12/12/2016
200          NULL            19/12/2016
```

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With only one value, the Oracle code is correct.  You can do what you want with conditional logic:

```
select employee_id,
       (case when max(date_column) <> min(date_column) then Max(Date_Column) end),
       Min(Date_Column)
from Employee_ID
where Date_Column is not null
Group by Employee_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gordon Linoff :)